# Boolean Implication

Tags: boolean-logic

I need some help with this Boolean Implication.

Can someone explain how this works in simple terms:

`A` implies `B = B + A'` (if A then B). Also equivalent to `A >= B`

Comment: No, he is correct - `+` means `or` here.

Comment: Did you mean A -> B = ~B -> ~A?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Boolean implication `A implies B` simply means "if A is true, then B must be true". This implies (pun intended) that if A isn't true, then B can be anything. Thus:

```
False implies False -> True
False implies True  -> True
True  implies False -> False
True  implies True  -> True
```

This can also be read as `(not A) or B` - i.e. "either A is false, or B must be true".

Comment: What definition of boolean implication do you have in mind? If you agree to "for a to imply b it is necessary and sufficient that b is always true when a is true", then see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29446256/1915854 . Implication is undefined for 3 cases you gave out of 4. Only when a=true and b=false you can truly conclude that (a=>b)=0 because you have a counterexample to (a=>b) (in words, a counterexample to "a implies b").

Comment: The definition is given in the very first sentence of the answer, and is the standard definition of implication in Boolean logic. You may find that it goes contrary to your common sense, but that is because you're taking a name of a very narrowly and strictly defined operator and projecting it outside of its scope of use, and mixing it up with a much broader linguistic definition of "implies". It is a common mistake for people newly introduced to formal Boolean logic, and it also happens with other operators (though implication is by far the most common due to the unfortunate name).

Comment: No "either ... or". If A=false and B=true then also "A implies B".

Comment: That's exactly what "either A is false, or B must be true" means.

Comment: Why is `False implies True -> True`? Seems counterintuitive.

Comment: By definition: "if A is true, then B must be true". Note that this doesn't say anything about what B must be when A is false. Therefore, when A is false, B can be anything.

Comment: It's a bit easier to grok if you recast it into a concrete statement. For example, consider the statement "X is a dog _implies_ that X is a mammal". This is undeniably true, isn't it? Now let's see what the truth table looks like here. If X is indeed a dog, the left part is true, and so is the right part: True implies True -> True. If X is a cat, then the first part is false, and the second part is true: False implies True -> True. What this is really saying is that a non-dog being a mammal does not invalidate the claim that all dogs are mammals.

Comment: Great word `(not A) or B`

Answer (score 36):

Here's how I think about it:

```c
if(A)
  return B;
else
  return True;
```

if A is true, then b is relevant and should be checked, otherwise, ignore B and return true.

Comment: Great explanation! As a one-liner `return A ? B : true;`

Answer (score 22):

I think I see where Serge is coming from, and I'll try to explain the difference. This is too long for a comment, so I'll post it as an answer.

Serge seems to be approaching this from the perspective of questioning whether or not the implication applies. This is somewhat like a scientist trying to determine the relationship between two events. Consider the following story:

> A scientist visits four different countries on four different days. In each country she wants to determine if rain implies that people will use umbrellas. She generates the following truth table:

```
Did it rain?  Did people      Does rain => umbrellas?  Comment
              use umbrellas?  
No            No              ??                       It didn't rain, so I didn't get to observe
No            Yes             ??                       People were shielding themselves from the hot sun; I don't know what they would do in the rain
Yes           No              No                       Perhaps the local government banned umbrellas and nobody can use them. There is definitely no implication here.
Yes           Yes             ??                       Perhaps these people use umbrellas no matter what weather it is
```

In the above, the scientist doesn't know the relationship between rain and umbrellas and she is trying to determine what it is. Only on one of the days in one of the countries can she definitively say that implies is not the correct relationship.

Similarly, it seems that Serge is trying to test whether A=>B, and is only able to determine it in one case.

However, when we are evaluating boolean logic we know the relationship ahead of time, and want to test whether the relationship was adhered to. Another story:

> A mother tells her son, "If you get dirty, take a bath" (dirty=>bath). On four separate days, when the mother comes home from work, she checks to see if the rule was followed. She generates the following truth table:

```
Get dirty?   Take a bath?   Follow rule?   Comment
No           No             Yes            Son didn't get dirty, so didn't need to take a bath. Give him a cookie.
No           Yes            Yes            Son didn't need to take a bath, but wanted to anyway. Extra clean! Give him a cookie.
Yes          No             No             Son didn't follow the rule. No cookie and no TV tonight.
Yes          Yes            Yes            He took a bath to clean up after getting dirty. Give him a cookie.
```

The mother has set the rule ahead of time. She knows what the relationship between dirt and baths are, and she wants to make sure that the rule is followed.

When we work with boolean logic, we are like the mother: we know the operators ahead of time, and we want to work with the statement in that form. Perhaps we want to transform the statement into a different form (as was the original question, he or she wanted to know if two statements are equivalent). In computer programming we often want to plug a set of variables into the statement and see if the entire statement evaluates to true or false.

It's not a matter of knowing whether implies applies - it wouldn't have been written there if it shouldn't be. Truth tables are not about determining whether a rule applies, they are about determining whether a rule was adhered to.

Answer (score 15):

I like to use the example: If it is raining, then it is cloudy.

```
Raining => Cloudy
```

Contrary to what many beginners might think, this in no way suggests that rain causes cloudiness, or that cloudiness causes rain. (**EDIT:** It means only that, **at the moment**, it **is not** both raining and not cloudy. See my recent blog posting on material implication [here](http://www.dcproof.com/IfPigsCanFly.html). There I develop, among other things, a rationale for the usual "definition" for material implication. The reader will require some familiarity with basic methods of proof, e.g. direct proof and proof by contradiction.)

```
~[Raining & ~Cloudy]
```

Comment: Don't you use the same sign "=>" when proving theorems, denoting that previous clause implies next clause? Also, you used "if-then" in your example, which suggests cause-effect relation. But you reversed cause and effect in that example: "cloudy" is the cause (but it's in "then" clause) and "raining" is the effect (but it's in "if" clause). Why not to use example like "for rain it is necessary that it is cloudy"? And then you could look at the truth tables and see that values except cloudy=0 and rain=1 indeed do not prove or disprove the statement, they only don't contradict.

Comment: In mathematics anyway, there is no cause and effect. As reflected in the standard truth table, Raining => Cloudy is only falsified if it is raining and not cloudy. Otherwise, it is true. This convention works really quite well. You will not come to any wrong conclusions in mathematics by using it.

Comment: An easy way to remember the expression for Implication, using a visualisation, is to consider what happens when it's not raining. When it's not raining, the sky may or may not be cloudy. So (not A) or B.

Comment: This is a great analogy.

Comment: Another good one is `Smoke => Fire`, correct? Based on the old saying "where there's smoke, there's fire." (Not based on reality, just the saying)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the truth tables, it is possible to infer the value of a=>b only for a=1 and b=0. In this case the value of a=>b is 0. For the rest of values (a,b), the value of a=>b is undefined: both (a=>b)=0 ("a doesn't imply b") and (a=>b)=1 ("a implies b") are possible:

```
a b a=>b comment
0 0  ?   it is not possible to infer whether a implies b because a=0
0 1  ?   --"--
1 0  0   b is 0 when a is 1, so it is possible to conclude
         that a does not imply b
1 1  ?   whether a implies b is undefined because it is not known
         whether b can be 0 when a=1 .
```

For a to imply b it is necessary and sufficient that b=1 always when a=1, so that there is no counterexample when a=1 and b=0. For the rows 1, 2 and 4 in the truth table it is not known whether there is counterexample: these rows do not contradict to (a=>b)=1, but they also do not prove (a=>b)=1 . In contrast, row 3 immediately disproves (a=>b)=1 because it provides a counterexample when a=1 and b=0.
I guess I may shock some readers with these explanations, but it seems there are severe errors somewhere in the basics of the logic we are taught, and that is one of the reasons for such problems as Boolean Satisfiability being not solved yet.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the basics of logic, just with some people's notions of implication. By definition, we have: A => B  =  ~[A & ~B]. See my answer.

Comment: How do you know whose notion is wrong? Why shouldn't implication denote cause-effect relation? Anyway, I like your answer assuming your notion of implication.

Comment: I know that the above equivalence works very well in mathematics. Just try to formulate an apparently incorrect result in mathematics that might stem from it. If you want to talk about cause and effect, you will need something in addition to mathematics. Just because there is a correlation between two events does not mean that one "causes" the other in the scientific sense of the word. A more in-depth analysis is required.

Answer (score 0):

The best contribution on this question is given by Serge Rogatch.

Boolean logic applies only where the result of quantifying(or evaluation) is either true or false and the relationship between boolean logic propositions is based on this fact.

So there must exist a relationship or connection between the propositions.

In higher order logic, the relationship is not just a case of on/off, 1/0 or +voltage/-voltage, the evaluation of a worded proposition is more complex. If no relationship exists between the worded propositions, then implication for worded propositions is not equivalent to boolean logic propositions.

While the implication truth table always yields correct results for binary propositions, this is not the case with worded propositions which may not be related in any way at all.

~A V B  truth table:

A   B   Result/Evaluation

1     1         1

1   0       0

0   1       1

0   0       1

Worded proposition A: The moon is made of sour cream.
Worded proposition B: Tomorrow I will win the lotto.

A   B    Result/Evaluation

1   ?           ?

As you can see, in this case, you can't even determine the state of B which will decide the result. Does this make sense now?

In this truth table, proposition ~A always evaluates to 1, therefore, the last two rows don't apply. However, the last two rows always apply in boolean logic.

http://thenewcalculus.weebly.com

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question particularly, but is basically just a rant; please don't post agreements with other answers (or comments) as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Comment: You make the same mistake many beginners do. Implication has nothing to with any "connections" or causality. By definition, A => B if and only if ~[A & ~B]. In words, we cannot have both A and not B. From your example: We cannot have both the moon made of sour cream and you not winning the lotto tomorrow. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: @DanChristensen , why don't you think that that definition is wrong? It deceives about the notion of implication. But even with that definition in words, every value pair in the truth table except A=1 and B=0 doesn't prove that "we cannot have both A and not B". Just think of what you have in truth table e.g. A=0 and B=0 - it is just an instance where your definition is not violated, where we indeed "do not have both A and not B". Why do you infer "we cannot" from "we do not"? Why do you generalize from the instance to every case necessary to prove that "we cannot"?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact statement:

Suppose we have two statements, A and B, each of which could either be true or false. Without any further information, there are 2 x 2 = 4 possibilities: "A and not B", "B and not A", "neither A nor B", and "both A and B".

Now impose the additional restriction that "if A, then also B". After imposing this restriction, the expression "x -> y", where -> is the "implication" operator, denotes **whether it is still possible** for A == x and B == y. The only outcome that is no longer possible after this additional restriction is A == 1 and B == 0, since that contradicts the restriction itself. Hence, we have 1 -> 0 is zero, and every other pair is 1.