# Are there any right associative short-circuit operators

Tags: language-design, short-circuiting

I'm working on a interrupter the lets one define their own operators. The goal then is to take an AST that looks like `exp op exp op exp` and turn it into either `exp op (exp op exp)` or `(exp op exp) op exp` based on the relative precedence and associativity of the two operators.  The language is dynamic so the only way to know what version of the operator to use is to evaluate the first expression and ask it what version of `op` to use.

On the other hand, it is important that we not evaluate the second expression because if `op` is `||` (as commonly used) then we should be able to short-circuit if the first `exp` is `false`.

a problem would arise if some operator were both right associative and short-circuiting.  **My question is are there any right associative, short-circuiting operators in common use** (for a chosen value of "common")?

N.b. assignment is handled separately by the parser so `=` is not an operator and `a (op)= b` is syntactic sugar for `a = a op b`.

Comment: Actually right associativity makes a hell of a lot more sense. Try to visualize the parse tree of `a or b or c or d or e`. When left-associative and `a` is true, we walk up and up and up the tree to get true at the top. When right-associative, if `a` is true, ta-da, we're done! So much easier to ignore the whole rest of the expression. Why do you say there's a problem with right-associativity? They both have the same behavior IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boolean implication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823168/boolean-implication) might be.

I would probably read

```
a → b → c
```

as "a implies that b implies c" which would suggest that it should parenthesize

```
a → (b → c)
```

and boolean implication should probably be short-circuiting since when a is false then the right side of (a → b) is irrelevant to the result.

Comment: Interesting! While it associates to the right, it short-circuits to the **left**, that is `a` will always be evaluated, but `b` is grouped with `c` not `a`.  I could still legitimately evaluate `a` to find the meaning of `→`.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller, other right associative operators usually evaluate left to right in languages where such things are well-defined.  Assignment is usually right associative, but in JavaScript the lhs is evaluated before the rhs: `var x = 42; var y = []; (x = y)[0] = x;` ends in the same state as the program `var y = []; x = y[0] = y;`.  I believe Java does the same; Python disallows assignment as a sub-expression; and C, C++, and OCaml do not specify evaluation order.

Comment: In case anyone lands here, Python started allowing assignments in expressions in 2019, but the previous comment was indeed correct for the time.