# Simplifying a Boolean expression

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

How would you simplify this boolean expression? I don't know how to apply the boolean laws with the implication sign.

(pq -> r)'

and

(p -> (q'r))'

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823168/boolean-implication

Answer (score 1):

The implication rule is as follows as stated in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication) or any other book related to logic:

```
p -> q = p' + q (not p or q)
```

therefore, when you apply rules to your examples, the step by step solution would be:

`((pq)' + r)'`

distribute the outer negation (2 negations cancel each other out and negation of disjunction is conjunction): yields `pqr'`

`(pq -> r)' = pqr'`

your second example is doable when you understand this answer, so I'll leave it to you:)