# Is there a bool.Implies(bool) extension method in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, boolean-logic

In which library is `bool.Implies(bool)` defined?

I would like to use it like `Assert.That (a.Implies(b))`.

I have an implementation, but would rather use a built-in one.

```
bool Implies(this bool a, bool b){
    return !a || b;
}
```

Comment: What does `Implies` do?

Comment: You mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823168/boolean-implication? I think only the compiler knows.

Comment: My research turned up... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model.implies(v=vs.93).aspx

Something to do with the 'Model' within the Solver Foundation 3.0

Comment: As you asked I added the implementation. It does NOT print anything or have any side-effects. It is a pure-function.

Comment: ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.model.implies(v=vs.93).aspx ?

Comment: [This documentation is for preview only, and is subject to change in later releases. …]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in the library. So I wrote my own.

```
static class myLogicExtensions {
    public static bool Implies(this bool a, bool b){
        return !a || b;
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems bizarre - so `false.Implies(true) = true`?

Comment: @D Stanley. Yes, it sounds weird. However remember that the false and true on the left are about different things. So let us put in some real predicates: For example if you ride the escalator you must wear shoes `escalator.amRiding implies shoes.amWearing`. If this predicate returns false then the safety police will come running in. Other examples `is computer implies has memory`, `is tree implies has branches`, `is circle implies is not square`, `light is on implies switch is on`, switch is on does not imply light is on, but `switch is off implies light is off`

Comment: I think I followed that except the last part: `light is on implies switch is on` but `light is off !implies switch is off`? Because the bulb could be burned out? But it definitely can't be on if the switch is off, right?

Answer (score 3):

There's an implementation of the `Imp` operator from VB 6. You can find it in [`Support.Imp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms652924%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) under the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6` namespace. However, for something this simple, I'd recommend just using your own method rather than introducing an additional dependency just for this method.

Comment: +1 for the arcane find, the words `Note: This API is now obsolete.` in the documentation dont inspire confidence.  Good recommendation.