# how to make an ⇒ and a ⇔ (logic connectives)?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I'm trying to evaluate this string:

```
var proposition = "(true&&false)⇒!true";
console.log(eval(proposition));
```

but that does not work because this "⇒" character, that is an unrecognized logic connective.

I was reading this answer post [Boolean Implication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823168/boolean-implication) but I still can't apply that to what I need.

I have this two functions that returns the implication and biconditional boolean result between two booleans values:

```
function Implication(v1,v2){
    return (!v1)||v2;               //implication formula
}

function Biconditional(v1,v2){
    if(v1==v2) return true;         //biconditional formula
    else return false;
}
```

And I can apply that functions for a specific logical proposition like this:

```
var proposition = "(true&&false)⇒!true";
var pars = proposition.split("⇒")
var result = Implication(eval(pars[0]),eval(pars[1]))
console.log(result)
```

And that works, but what if I have something like: "((true⇔true)&&false)⇒false⇔true||false"  or any other convination?

Comment: You'd have to build your own parser or use something like [Jison](http://zaa.ch/jison/). There is no built-in way to do it.

Comment: ty, i'll check that Jison.

Comment: The biconditional operator is already supported in JavaScript. It's called `===`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks! now I just need the ⇒ implementation.

Comment: Hm, you could use `==false||` but have to make sure that every operand is properly grouped.

Comment: @Bergi how is that ==false||? Can you example it? because I already have the algorithm to make sure that every operand will be properly grouped.

Comment: You can replace the `⇒` operator in `v1⇒v2` with that string: `v1==false||v2`.

Comment: I still don't understand, are you talking about Implication function?