What is the meaning of `=>` in Lustre?
In Lustre v6 syntax rules, there is a => expression
Expression ::= ...
            |  Expression => Expression 
            ... 

It seems that => accepts 2 boolean operands and also returns a boolean value. The truth table for c = a => b is as follows:



a
b
c




1
1
1


1
0
0


0
1
1


0
0
1



But in lustre v6 reference manual, there is no detailed illustration on expression =>.

https://kind.cs.uiowa.edu/kind2_user_docs/lustre_primer.pdf says it's boolean implies, which seems to match the table on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35050567/529282
